MOSFET for level shifting - Gate to GND?
I am looking at the bottom left of page 13 of this schematics. It has a level shifter on a UART interface from 1.8V to 3.3V. For some reason they connected the Gate to GND though, which seems weird to me. Can someone explain why it was done this way, or is this simply a mistake that will never work?
The schematics look similar to this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Seems a mistake to me.

… and the "correct" gate voltage of 1.8 V would not be appropriate for the 2N7002.

looks like a cursed attempt to mimic NXP  AN10441 figure 1

Short answer: It's a mistake.

The gates are grounded, and the sources are tied to 1V8. In this way, the MOSFETs can't be turned on unless, for example, UART1_RX is pulled down to a negative voltage (e.g. -2V) which doesn't seem to be possible, judging from the overall circuit. UART1_RX comes from the level shifter's output which swings between 1V8 and 0V (there's another 10k pull-up there but it doesn't have any effect on overall behaviour) so the UART-RX which goes to J2 (probably for an external connection) will never see a logic-0.
The only meaningful thing I can see is that if UART-TX is pulled low by an external circuitry the body diode of Q3 will be forward-biased so UART1_TX may see a logic-0. However, I say "may" because the voltage at that node will be 0.6~0.7V which is just in the vicinity of the 35% of 1V8 (the VIL of the level shifter for VCC = 1.65 ~ 1.95V) so it may or may not be seen as a logic-0 (with 200 μA bias current the drop could be less, though).
PS: The schematic you linked is revision C3, released in July 2014. On revision C6 released in Feb 2016, the level shifters shown above have been removed.

The schematic linked is based on the one you linked, but it is a changed design. C6 is missing the UART-Connector entirely.
Oddly enough, the PCB I have was missing these 2 FETs (they were unpopulated), however it does not match the schematics, the gate is not grounded. I added Si2342DS but the TX from the board is garbled sometimes, RX works fine. Unfortunately I do not know how the circuit looks like or what resistors there are and where they are connected to.
